# ZF2 two elements with one input filter

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I have a simple zend framework 2 form and input filter.  I'm trying to figure out how to validate that the expiration year and month of a credit card to not fall into the past.  How can you have one validation rule that requires two fields to validate correclty?

Input filter:

```
<?php
namespace Account\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Validator\CreditCard;
use Zend\Validator\Date;

class SuspendedPaymentFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {


    $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'expiration_month',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
           array('name' => 'not_empty'),
           array(
                'name' => 'date',
                'options' => array(
                    'locale' => 'en',
                    'format' => 'm',
                ),
            ),
         ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'expiration_year',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array('name' => 'not_empty'),
            array(
                'name' => 'date',
                'options' => array(
                    'locale' => 'en',
                    'format' => 'Y',
                ),
            ),
         ),
    ));


}
}
```

Form:

```
<?php
namespace Account\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Tools\Data\DateTime;

class PaymentForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('Payment');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');



    $this->add(array(
        'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'expiration_month',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required',
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Expiration Month',
            'value_options' => array(
                '01' => 'January',
                '02' => 'February',
                '03' => 'March',
                '04' => 'April',
                '05' => 'May',
                '06' => 'June',
                '07' => 'July',
                '08' => 'August',
                '09' => 'September',
                '10' => 'October',
                '11' => 'November',
                '12' => 'December',
            ),

        ),

    ));

   $this->add(array(
        'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'expiration_year',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required',
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Expiration Year',
            'value_options' =>  DateTime::returnXYears(10),
        ),

    ));

}
}
```

Comment: Have a look  here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529906/zf2-validation-how-can-i-validate-dependent-fields/17532467#17532467

Answer (score -1):

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'date_serv',
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'NotEmpty',
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array( 
                            'isEmpty' => 'Debe ingresar fecha de creación',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array( 
                    'name'=>'Date',
                    'break_chain_on_failure'=>true,
                    'options'=>array(
                        'format'=>'Y-m-d',
                        'messages'=>array(
                            'dateFalseFormat'=>'Formato fecha invalida, debe ser dd-mm-yyyy',
                            'dateInvalidDate'=>'Fecha ínvalida'
                        ),
                    ),     
                ),
                array(
                    'name'    => 'Between',
                    'options' => array(
                        'min' => '1970-01-01',
                        'max' => date('Y-m-d'),
                        'messages' => array( 
                            'notBetween' => 'La fecha de creación no puede ser mayor a la fecha actual',
                        ),
                    ),

                ),
            ),
        )));
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how this solves the OP's problem.